# Iteratively build string with different sized inputs

Tags: python, list, loops

Sorry if this is a confusing way to word the question, quick psuedo code before I try to explain it:

```
#for my purpose its to build urls

base='www.page.com/'
list1=['a','b','c','d']
list2=['1','2','3']
list3=['orange','blue','white','yellow','red','green']

for index in each list:
    base+=base+/list1[idx]/list2[idx]/list3[idx]

    #desired output: 'www.page.com/a/1/orange', 'www.page.com/b/1/orange' 
    #and so on filling in each of them as I go
```

So what I'm trying to do is build urls with the different patterns of endings at the end.

I'm not sure where to go. I've tried nested for loops but it gave me an infinite loop:

```py
    for i in list1:
        for j in list2:
            for k in list3:
                base+=base+'  '+i+' '+j+' '+k
                print(base)
```

Any help is appreciated. Also if you could explain how it works that would be fantastic as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an infinite loop, but you keep appending to `base` which you should not. Just do:

```
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        for k in list3:
            url = base + i + '/' + j + '/' + k
            print(url)
```

Or you can be a little more concise, using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

base='www.page.com'  # remove '/'
# list1 = ...
# ...

for p in product(list1, list2, list3):
    print('/'.join([base, *p]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it will overflow base, or it just takes a long time to finish.

**Explanation**: so your initial string has length: 13

Your lists have a length of: 4, 3 and 6

After the first loop base has a size of 13 + 13+1+1+1+1+1+6 = 37

More or less the size of your base increases by at least 2 each iteration:

So at the end the size of base is roughly: 13*2^(4*3*6) = 61390764277305387778048

Which might be a tad large ;)

**Fix**:

```
base=['www.page.com/']
list1=['a','b','c','d']
list2=['1','2','3']
list3=['orange','blue','white','yellow','red','green']

for i in list1:
        for j in list2:
            for k in list3:
                base.add(base[0]'  '+i+' '+j+' '+k)
                print(base[len(base)])
```